# No such thing as PIL when importing python Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, importerror

So, I tried to import the 'ImageDraw' but it doesn't work, please help. Here is the code:

```
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Comment: [Did you install Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)?

Answer (score 0):

**you didn't install pillow package!**

```
pip install pillow
```